# Why isn't knob dial/tron css working with dynamic html

Tags: jquery, html

I have implemented the [Knob jquery plugin](https://github.com/aterrien/jQuery-Knob) on my website. My html code containing the knob input fields are generated dynamically using jquery. The challenge is that the text input field isn't converted to a knob dial. However, if I put the knob html code directly into my php page the dial display just fine. Does anyone know why the dynamic html isn't displaying the knob dial? Please see my code below:

Including the js file:

```
<script src="bower_components/jquery-knob/js/jquery.knob.js"></script>
```

The knob configuration function:

```
$(function () {
/* jQueryKnob */

$(".knob").knob({
  /*change : function (value) {
   //console.log("change : " + value);
   },
   release : function (value) {
   console.log("release : " + value);
   },
   cancel : function () {
   console.log("cancel : " + this.value);
   },*/

  draw: function () {

    // "tron" case
    if (this.$.data('skin') == 'tron') {

      var a = this.angle(this.cv)  // Angle
          , sa = this.startAngle          // Previous start angle
          , sat = this.startAngle         // Start angle
          , ea                            // Previous end angle
          , eat = sat + a                 // End angle
          , r = true;

      this.g.lineWidth = this.lineWidth;

      this.o.cursor
      && (sat = eat - 0.3)
      && (eat = eat + 0.3);

      if (this.o.displayPrevious) {
        ea = this.startAngle + this.angle(this.value);
        this.o.cursor
        && (sa = ea - 0.3)
        && (ea = ea + 0.3);
        this.g.beginPath();
        this.g.strokeStyle = this.previousColor;
        this.g.arc(this.xy, this.xy, this.radius - this.lineWidth, sa, ea, false);
        this.g.stroke();
      }

      this.g.beginPath();
      this.g.strokeStyle = r ? this.o.fgColor : this.fgColor;
      this.g.arc(this.xy, this.xy, this.radius - this.lineWidth, sat, eat, false);
      this.g.stroke();

      this.g.lineWidth = 2;
      this.g.beginPath();
      this.g.strokeStyle = this.o.fgColor;
      this.g.arc(this.xy, this.xy, this.radius - this.lineWidth + 1 + this.lineWidth * 2 / 3, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
      this.g.stroke();

      return false;
    }
  }
});
/* END JQUERY KNOB */
});
```

Dynamic html created using jquery:

```
 for (var i in theConfirmedGuests )
        {
            var evrow = theConfirmedGuests[i];
            var confirmed = evrow['confirmed'];
            var ev_guests = evrow['totalguests'];

            var percentage_tmp = (confirmed/ev_guests)*100;
            var percentage = percentage_tmp.toFixed(0);

$('#output_cal_search').append("<div class='col-xs-6 col-md-3 text-center'> 
<input type='text' class='knob' value='"+percentage+"' data-skin='tron' 
'data-thickness='0.1' data-width='90' data-height='90' data- 
fgColor='#00a65a'><div class='knob-label'>data-thickness='0.1'</div> 
</div>");
```

and finally the html code:

```
 <table class="table table-hover">
          <thead>
            <tr>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
            <th>ID</th>
              <th>Customer</th>
              <th>Start</th>
              <th>End</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id = "output_cal_search">
           </tbody>
          </table>
```

Below is the html code working if I put it directly into my php file which is the same code as I use in the dynamich html output:

```
           <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 text-center">
              <input type="text" class="knob" value="10" data-skin="tron" 
         data-thickness="0.1" data-width="90" data-height="90" data- fgColor="#00a65a">

              <div class="knob-label">data-thickness="0.1"</div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize the knob on the dynamically added content. This should do it, placed after the `.append()`:

```
$('input.knob', '#output_cal_search').knob();
```

Note the second param, denominating the context. You could, of course, re-init on the entire document:

```
$('input.knob').knob(); // equivalent to $('input.knob', document).knob()
```

...if, and **only if**, there are no downsides to re-init-ing all your knobs (don't lose values, don't throw errors).

If `#output_cal_search` contains old and new knobs and you can't re-init old ones, your only option is to add a custom class to each dynamically added container (along the lines of `needs-init`), and use that class to only target the newly added content:

```
$('input.knob', '.needs-init').knob();
// and remove the class immediately after:
$('.needs-init').removeClass('needs-init');
```

I would place the knob initialization outside of the `for` loop (especially if you reinit all the knobs in your page), but I guess it would work inside it as well.